# Should I inline namespace scope lambdas? In either case, why?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, inline, one-definition-rule

Sometimes I have some capture-less lambda defined at the top of a header file, which is used in the following part of the header:

```cpp
//#include statements
namespace detail {
auto constexpr lambda = [](/* args */){ /* body */ };
}
// in some function or whatever, use `lambda`
```

Often I'm told in during code reviews that I should put not only `constexpr` specifier, as I do, but also the `inline` specifier.

Why should I do that? What are the advantages?

I've tried reading [`inline` specifier on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline), but I think I lack to much terminology to understand it at the moment.

Comment: Just curious = why a non-capturing lambda instead of regular function ?

Comment: @Bktero, so I can pass it around as an object, e.g. as a predicate for filtering, grouping, or whatever. I couldn't do that with a template function. (The lambda I'm using is a generic lambda.) Lambdas are just more versitile than functions. And with C++20, lambdas with template parameter list reach parity with hand written `struct`+`operator()`, I believe.

Comment: You can do it with regular functions, but I hadn't think about template functions. Interesting trick, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, probably it would have been more apparent if I had written `auto var` instead of `/* args */` to make it clear the lambda is generic (and so it corresponds to template functions), but that wasn't relevant to my question so I skipped. Happy to help, @Bktero :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `inline` if the variable is defined in a header file.  If it is not inline, then every translation unit that includes the header file will get that definition.  That means you have multiple definitions for a single name which is an ODR ([One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)) violation.  Those do not require any diagnostics, so they can lead to hard to find bugs.

By making the variable inline, you fix the problem by telling the compiler/linker that it can throw out all of the duplicated definitions and just use a single one.

Comment: Your explanation is crystal clear, thanks. To help me understand this stuff myself in the future, would you help me single out the part of the doc on [`inline` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) which expresses what you explained? I see that the ODR is mentioned only at 2.1, where it reads _There may be more than one definition of an inline function [...]_. Is that the one?

Comment: @Enlico Yes.  Section 2.1 there describes how `inline` allows each translation unite to contain an identical definition in contradiction to ODR.

Comment: @Enlico Also, right before the notes section there is *Because the meaning of the keyword inline for functions came to mean "multiple definitions are permitted" rather than "inlining is preferred", that meaning was extended to variables.*

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (10.1.5 The constexpr specifier)

> 1 The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a
> variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or
> function template. **A function or static data member declared with
> the constexpr specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable
> (10.1.6).** If any declaration of a function or function template has
> a constexpr specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the
> constexpr specifier.

In the code snippet in your question the variable `lambda` is not a static data member.

```
namespace detail {
auto constexpr lambda = [](/* args */){ /* body */ };
}
```

So if the namespace `detail` has external linkage then and the variable `lambda` also has the external linkage.  In this case if the header will be included in several compilation units then the one definition rule will be broken. To avoid such a situation you should declare the variable as an inline variable.